# Где послушать произношение русских идиом?

Tags: resources, idioms, фонетика

Уважаемые знатоки, пожалуйста, посоветуйте ресурс, где можно услышать русские фразеологизмы, идиомы, сленг в концентрированном виде.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под «концентрированным видом», я так понимаю, вы имеете в виду просто-напросто «целиком, а не по словам».

В таком случае на [Forvo](http://ru.forvo.com) должны быть. Но, понятное дело, есть там не все. Однако, я попытался навскидку вспомнить пять фразеологизмов, что могут вызвать затруднения при чтении с листа — все пять я там нашел без проблем:

- из-под выподверта / исподвыподверта [[F]](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0/#ru)
- тихой сапой [[F]](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9/)
- Держать ухо востро [[F]](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE/)
- Пришла беда — отворяй ворота [[F]](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_-_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/#ru)
- Лиха беда начало [[F]](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE/#ru)

Впрочем, доверять Forvo, как и всякому вики-ресурсу, надо осторожно, например в виражении «Из огня — да в полымя» [[F]](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F/#ru) некто Милослава из Кемеровской области выбрала довольно удивительное ударение на второй слог в слове *полымя* — *полы́мя* — против нормального *по́лымя*. Возможно, это региональное.

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий!
Forvo - удивительный ресурс.
Правда, мне пока не понять, как там заказать озвучивание фраз.
Разберусь.
"Из огня да в полымя" - мне всегда казалось, что естественное ударение на последний слог, потому что так в рифму.

Comment: @BrainsFeeder Всегда пожалуйста. Заказать озвучивание за деньги (слово «заказать» подразумевает именно возмездную основу), насколько я понимаю, там нельзя. Попросить озвучить ту или иную фразу — вроде-бы тоже.

Comment: @BrainsFeeder Что до ударения в слове _полымя_, то в порядке поэтической вольности может быть и _полымя́_, но вообще такой парадигмы склонения в русском языке, вроде бы, нет. _Полы́мя_ же быть не должно хотя бы потому, что оно вообще-то _поломя_ — через _о_, и будь это _о_ в сильной позиции в _ы_ бы оно не превратилось.

Comment: @BrainsFeeder И еще, поскольку вы на R.SO недавно, позволю себе вам напомнить, что здесь желательно закрывать вопросы, если вы получили на них ответ, путем [выбора ответа](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), который вы считаете наиболее полным (ваш собственный вы ответ тоже можете выбрать).

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий, за науку. А "в концентрированном виде" - я имел в виду "все вместе", "сразу много". Может быть, эту мысль можно выразить иначе?

Comment: @BrainsFeeder По-моему, это уточнение просто избыточно (то есть и так понятно, что чем больше, тем лучше), но можно сказать «в большом количестве».

Answer (score 4):

Я нашёл программу "РазгРусс" (разговорный русский).
В ней очень много идиом, записанных из песен, фильмов, теле- и радиопередач.
Наслаждаюсь.

Comment: Презабавная штука, спасибо (+1). Но несколько пар вида <изучаемое выражение> — <толкование> удивляют — второе едва ли понятнее первого, мне попались: _бездарное произведение_ — _бесталанное творение_, _бездомная кошка_ — _бродячая кошка_, а _он выбился из сил_ — _он изнемог_.